# What do you call someone who can't keep secrets?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, pejorative-language

Some one who is not good at keeping secrets. In my native language it is called "chugalkhor" but it's a slang. So I can't translate it.

What do you call such a person who can't keep secrets because his instincts don't let him.

Comment: *open*, *tactless* ...

Comment: Too tired to bother writing a well-formed answer, but "loose-lipped" springs to mind.

Comment: loose-lipped hmm..

Comment: dictionary.com say *stupid* is an antonym of sly (not that sly is the opposite of someone who can't keep secrets - but it's nice...)

Comment: Really, vaibhav, what don't you like about the current responses that would prompt you to look for more? Perhaps you should explain what's wrong with the banana-boatload of synonyms you've already been given.

Comment: Julian Assange.

Comment: "Gossip" is getting too little attention, in my opinion. Don

Comment: Hi. I just noticed you haven't accepted any answers to your questions so far. You should mark the most helpful answer accepted, by clicking on the check mark next to the post score on their left side; in addition to up-voting and awarding bounties.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First thing I would like to point out - *chugalkhor* doesn't seem to just mean 'can't keep a secret'. More like somebody who is actively **complaining about / revealing others' wrongdoings**, not 'not keeping secrets'. So the question's premise itself seems wrong.

Now going on to an English word:

**An English word meaning the same thing as *chugalkhor*:**

> - **tattletale**: someone who gossips indiscreetly
> - **tattler**: synonym of *tattletale*
> - **taleteller**:  synonym of *tattletale*
> - **telltale**: synonym of *tattletale*
> - **sneak**: *British Informal* tattletale; informer
> - **snitch**: Also called snitcher; an informer.
> - **backbiter**: one who speaks unfavorably or slanderously of a person who is not present.

-[Source of words from shabdkosh.com](http://www.shabdkosh.com/hi/translate?e=%E0%A4%9A%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B0&l=hi) and source of meanings is from [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/)

Of the above words, **tattletale** and the other highly similar synonyms related to **tattle** come closest to the way your given word is used.

> (eta) **chugali** is entirely defined as **tattling** and **telling tales** in this [Hindi-English dictionary](http://hindi-english.org/index.php?input=chugali&trans=Translate&direction=AU) I just discovered.

A **sneak** is regional and also implies cowardliness, and a **snitch** can often specifically imply one informing the authorities such as the police. And a **backbiter** can backbite in more ways than *tattling* - he can just spread uncomplimentary information (true or false) unrelated to actual wrongdoing.

**An English word for *someone who can't keep a secret***

> - **blabbermouth**: a person who talks too much, especially **indiscreetly**.
> - **indiscreet**: not discreet, i.e. not "judicious in one's conduct or speech, especially with regard to respecting privacy or maintaining silence about something of a delicate nature."

A **blabbermouth** is not exact, since a blabbermouth can talk too much about things that *aren't* secrets, but the phrase usually does imply a person who wouldn't be able to 'keep it in' while *blabbering* if they were in possession of a secret.

But it's a bit closer than a plain **indiscreet** which can and does also apply as frequently to conduct not just talk, and more importantly can refer to being careless with  *one's own* affairs and secrets, not just others'.

**Loose-lipped** is another colloquialism for the concept, if not one you're likely to find in a dictionary. One of the sayings to popularize the phrase is the WWII slogan *[Loose lips sink ships](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_lips_sink_ships)*; but apparently the phrase was also used by Virginia Woolf (1882-1941).

Comment: I don't believe that "loose-lipped" derives from that phrase, it's older than that. M-W cites Virginia Woolf, for example. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loose-lipped

Comment: @Rupe I'll have to take your word for it - MW seems to be behind a paywall for me. :( I'll update my answer to reflect this, thanks :)

Answer (score 45):

The first word I think of is

- [Blabbermouth](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blabbermouth?q=blabbermouth)

> A person who talks excessively or indiscreetly. -- from ODO
>   
>   The [thesaurus lists several synonyms with negative connotations](http://thesaurus.com/browse/blabbermouth), such as when a criminal reports on his associates' activities:

- Rat
- Fink
- Snitch
- Squealer
- Informant

Comment: Blabbermouth instantly jumped to my mind too, but a note to the OP: I can't quite tell what you're after, but "blabbermouth" is extremely colloquial, even childish.

Comment: A lot of your synonyms suggest a person who is deliberately informing on someone, rather than someone who can't help themselves. I think your answer could be improved if you mentioned that.

Comment: Re: @starsplusplus comment, I would go so far as to say you should remove the synonyms entirely.  They do not meet the criteria of the question and end up cluttering what is otherwise an excellent answer.

Answer (score 17):

You can also call this person:

[Big mouth](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=big%20mouth&defid=2811648):

> used in reference to somebody who likes to spread gossip, *or who cannot keep a secret*.

Note also the expression:

Someone who [spill the beans/the works](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spill+the+beans):

> Fig. to give away a secret or a surprise.
>
> There is a surprise party for Heidi on Wednesday. Please don't spill the beans. Paul spilled the works about Heidi's party.
> See also: bean, spill

Source: http://www.urbandictionary/ http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com

Answer (score 13):

A *gossip*. I like this word because it less about ratting someone out, and more about talking about other people and telling others what they've confided in you.

The word *gossip* is also less of a slang/colloquial word, as some of the answers suggested, so it would suit more forms of communication.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the implication from [this page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/I-HATE-CHUGAL-KHOR-AUNTIES/117778964928966), this is referring to a [gossip](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gossip&oq=gossip&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j0.1399j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=gossip%20definition) which can be a noun or a verb. There are many synonyms [proper](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gossip&oq=gossip&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j0.1399j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=gossip%20synonym) and [slang](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gossip&oq=gossip&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j0.1399j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=gossip%20synonyms%20slang) for (a) gossip so you could take your pick for a good translation of the intent.

With regard to **"his instincts don't let him"**, you could use some type of descriptor like **'natural born'**, **'pathological'**, **'compulsive'** or just **'instinctual'** combined with one of the synonyms for gossip so depending on what sort of audience this is for you could say 'pathological gossip' (proper; you would need to provide some evidence of this) or 'compulsive chin-wag' (slang) for example.

Answer (score 5):

A person you cannot keep secrets can be called *indiscreet*, a *blabbermouth*.

See [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blabbermouth) for more synonyms of *blabbermouth*.

Comment: The answer *blabbermouth* was already given.

Comment: so sorry didn't see that.

Answer (score 3):

I like [*tattletale*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tattletale), which “the Free Dictionary” defines as:

> tat·tle·tale  (ttl-tl)
>      n.
>      One who tattles on others; an informer or talebearer.

Comment: This isn't about keeping secrets, it's about ratting out someone for the purpose of getting them in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

*Tattletale* is the right word for such a person.

Comment: This is about getting someone in trouble, not an inability to keep secrets. Someone who reveals what another is getting as a birthday gift is not a tattletale.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus : you might as well want to take a look at the definition of this word.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of these:

**sycophant** - a person who acts obsequiously towards someone important in order to gain advantage.

**talebearer** - a person who maliciously gossips or reveals secrets.

**tattler** - a person who engages in gossip or who tells tales.

**gossiper / gossipmonger** - a person who enjoys talking about other people's private lives : a person who spreads gossip

**newsmonger** - a person who spreads gossip or idle talk

**quidnunc** -     an inquisitive and gossipy person.

**tale-teller** - a person who spreads gossip or reveals secrets.

**telltale** - a person, especially a child, who reports others' wrongdoings or reveals their secrets.

**yenta** - a woman who is a gossip or busybody

**whistle-blower** - a person who informs on a person or organization regarded as engaging in an unlawful or immoral activity.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on the context.

If the person in question has sworn in to his country, and breaches security via communicating secret information, they'd be called an `oath-breaker`, or `traitor`. If they were communicating information the country did illegally, they might be considered a `Whistleblower`.

If it's in a social setting, a formal descriptor would be `scandalmonger` or `flibbertigibbet`.

More informal words for a social setting would be (as mentioned) `blabbermouth` or `telltale`/`tattletale`.

If you're most concerned about the word containing instinctive elements, I'd say your closest bet would be `flibbertigibbet`:

> flib·ber·ti·gib·bet
>   /ˈflɪbərtiˌdʒɪbɪt/ [flib-er-tee-jib-it] [source][1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flibbertigibbet?s=t)
>
> noun
>
> 1.
>   a chattering or flighty, light-headed person.
>
> 2.
>   Archaic. a gossip.
>
> Origin:
>   1425–75; late Middle English flepergebet, flipergebet;  reduplicative compound of obscure origin

Answer (score 1):

I am joining this conversation very late, but generally let me add a couple of comments. First, perhaps you need more than one word to get at the meaning in English that you need. Somewhere I saw a great descriptive phrase "prodigal tongue". A prodigal (think of the biblical story of the prodigal son) is basically a "spendthrift"; a person who cannot help but spend the money he or she has. In Ancient Rome, a prodigal was considered mentally incompetent and in need of a guardian for his or her finances, because he or she couldn't help it. If that's the sort of thing you're after, describing the person as having a "prodigal tongue" -- in other words, unable to control telling, might be a good solution.

The other comment is that "bitching" refers most of the time to women. I might use "grousing" if you want something more generic. A "grouse" is a complainer -- but that seemed less to the point.

Comment: I disagree that "bitching" refers most of the time to women. *Bitching* is used for 'complaining', with the sexist implication that the griping is not masculine as an additional insult.

Answer (score 0):

If this word you seek is about someone who is talking about you to reveal secrets or information for the purpose of causing trouble, then I would consider the word *snitch*.  According to Merriam-Webster, "a snitch is a person who tells someone in authority about something wrong that someone has done."  The implication for snitch is that the act of snitching is intended to cause some kind of trouble for you.  The intent of a snitch is usually malicious.

If the person in question didn't really intend any harm, then some of the above suggestions such as *loose-lipped, blabber-mouth, gossip*, or even *indiscreet* may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a proverb in the Old Testament book of Proverbs which talks about the kind of person you describe:

> "He who goes about as a **talebearer** reveals secrets, But he who is trustworthy conceals a matter" (Proverbs 11:13 NAS, my emphasis).

A synonym for a "talebearer" is a "gossip." A gossip is someone who cannot keep a confidence (or secret).

In Hebrew (the original language of Proverbs), the proverb would be much simplified:

> "Talebearer reveals; trustworthy person conceals" (or something like that).

Interestingly, in America, a saying that we associate with a person's (insincere) promise *not* to divulge a secret is:

> "Do you swear on your mother's grave?"

And the talebearer's duplicitous response is:

> "I swear on my mother's grave."

Answer (score -1):

Although many synonyms have been given above, I believe the literal translation for *chugli* is *bitching*.

"Chugalkhor" is a hindi slang, the meaning being "gossiping with malicious intent".

For example an approximate translation of "wo mere dost ke samne meri chugli kar rahi thi" (sorry, I could not find the exact Devanagari script) would be "they were bitching about me to my friend."